# Django format urls

Tags: django, url, format

I'm new to Django so i'm sorry if this question is noobish. I want to format Django urls which are received from GET and are something like this:

```
example.com/search?title=Test&city=London&category=SomeCategory
example.com/search?title=&city=London&category=SomeCategory
example.com/search?title=&city=&category=SomeCategory
```

into this:

```
example.com/search/Test/London/SomeCategory
example.com/search/post/London/SomeCategory
example.com/search/post/city/SomeCategory
```

What is the best way to do this? How will the form submitting this look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<title>\w+)/(?P<city>[\w -_]+)/(?P<category>[\w -_]+/$',
     'name_of_view', name='name_of_view')
```

... with such a view:

```
def name_of_view(request, title, city, category):
    ...
```

Your form then, would look along the following lines:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url name_of_view title city category %}">
  ...
</form>
```

Point is that you need to provide default arguments for when some parts aren't needed (like `title` or `city`, as per your example). You do have to supply them in the url though. This means that when handling them in your view, you need to check if they do have some special value, and process the values conditionally.

*Note that I took some educated guesses for the regexes in the url patterns: adapt if needed.*